# How can I use the Arduino library Wifi-Manager on Mongoose OS?

Tags: arduino, webserver

I started using Mongoose OS recently, however I did not find a way to create a wifi network for my user to choose the wifi and enter the password.

This [Arduino library](https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager) does exactly that. I would like to know how I can use it in Mongoose or if there is a similar one.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for their wifi library and you want to enable `ap` mode.  The library is located here:

https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/wifi

For MongooseOS you add this library to your `mos.yml` file in the `libs` directory, e.g.:

```
libs:
  ...
  - origin: https://github.com/cesanta/mos-libs/tree/master/wifi
  - origin: https://github.com/cesanta/mos-libs/tree/master/mjs
```

You can set some of the default config in the same `yml` file:

```
config_schema:
  - ["wifi.sta.enable", true]
  - ["wifi.ap.enable", true]
  - ["wifi.ap.ssid", "SSIDPREFIX_??????"]
  - ["wifi.ap.pass", "YOURPWD"]
  - ["wifi.ap.hostname", "configure.yourdomain.com"]
```

In this example, I am also using the new `hostname` option added in December 2017 - once you connect to your device, you can visit that hostname and you should be prompted for your actual wifi SSID/password.

Comment: He's not asking how to connect to WiFi, he's asking how to make a captive portal which allows users to decide which WiFi network to connect to. Read the linked library.

Comment: The mongoose `ap` configuration enables an access point served by the device - a wifi network generated by the microcontroller. Users connect to this network in order to provide the device a SSID/password that will be used to connect to the actual internet. You can read about the two config modes: https://github.com/mongoose-os-libs/wifi (same link as in the answer) and see a reference app here: https://github.com/mongoose-os-apps/wifi-setup-web/blob/master/fs/index.html